# Microsoft Project 2010 Task Outlinelevel in C# causing run-time exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ms-project

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015 to add Tasks to MS Project and change the outline level.  While I am able to add tasks, I am getting run-time error when I try to change the `OutlineLevel`.  I found out that the `Task.OutlineLevel` is a `short` and so I tried several things to cast to `short` - nothing worked. Here is the code.

```
private void button_Taskcount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int16 level;
    // label_counttasks.Text = myProject.Name + "has " + myProject.Tasks.Count + " tasksom" ;
    MSProject.Project myProject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;


    MSProject.Task myTask;
    myTask = myProject.Tasks.Add("New Task");

    myTask = myProject.Tasks.Add("New Task 2",myTask.UniqueID);

    level = (Int16)(myTask.OutlineLevel + 1);
    myTask.OutlineLevel = level;
}
```

I get an error that says "The argument is invalid".  I have spent 6 hours on it..

I want to change the outline level of `myTask`.  I also tried `myTask.OutlineIndent()` - it gives the same error.

Comment: According to MSDN, Task.OutlineLevel is an `integer`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864527(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Exactly which line is it blowing up on?

Comment: By the way, at least according to the documentation, the second parameter to `Tasks.Add` should be the position the task will take in the tasks collection.  The `Task.UniqueID` isn't that: it's an identifier.  While it might be the same as the position for the first few tasks, you can't assume it will always be.

Comment: Task.Outlinelevel is a short in Project 2010 and integer in 2013 :0(

Comment: The error is in the last line where I change the outline level.  If I say myTask.Outlinelevel = myTask.Outlinelevel it works, but nothing with another number i.e, myTask.Outlinelevel = 2 or (short)2 doesnt work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after 6 more hours of searching.  It turns out that I was trying to change the outlinelevel of the first task, which is not allowed.  For the second task I was adding, I was using the "before" parameter as the first task. So the task was added as the first task. So when I tried to change the outline level of the added task (which is now the first task), it complained, as expected, as you cannot make the outline level of the first task greater than 1.